# C# create a list of objects from a list of properties

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to minimize this.

```
List<ClassB> foo(List<ClassA> listA)
{
    var listB = new List<ClassB>();
    foreach (var item in listA)
        listB.Add(new ClassB(item, "stuff"));

    return listB;
}
```

Is there any way I can minimize this using LINQ? I want to minimize this because there are ton of conversions like this in my codebase, and generics can not deal with quirks of the various classes to be converted.

Comment: Yes, there is. Have you tried any linq? (`Select`) Please show what you have tried. We can help from there

Comment: If there are "quirks" for every class then no, there is no general solution to solve a non-general problem. For the specific code in the question you can just do `listA.Select(item => new ClassB(item, "stuff")).ToList()`, but if the construction of the other class is different in every case then 1 general simple one-liner won't work.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but with `Select` I can just select a few (or all) from the original list. But how do I convert them to a list of `classB`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The current code (doesn't matter what the classes look like, because we suspect the current code works) can be converted to linq

Comment: @Crimson7 listA.Select(a => new ClassB(a, "stuff")).ToList()

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, the "quirks" I am talking about is mostly with the constructor. Some have 1 parameter, some have more and so on

Comment: @Crimson7 - select is used for projection. What you are thinking about is `Where`. Refer to MSDN

Comment: @vc74 that works! Put it as an answer so I can select it

Comment: @GiladGreen Ah, got it! Got confused between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Select` method is what you need. What it basically does is transforming each element in the enumerable to something else. In this case, you are transforming all the `ClassA` to `ClassB`.

The argument for `Select` is a method that takes an instance of `ClassA` and returns a `ClassB`. In this case, the method looks like this:

```
ClassB MyMethod(ClassA obj) {
    return new ClassB(obj, "stuff");
}
```

This can be written in lambda expression form:

```
obj => new ClassB(obj, "stuff")
```

You pass this to `Select`, call `ToList` to turn the `IEnumerable` to a `List<ClassB>` and it's done!

```
List<ClassB> foo(List<ClassA> listA)
{
    return listA.Select(obj => new ClassB(obj, "stuff")).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I think he means `listA.Select`. Thanks for the explanation as well. I will mark it as an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a lot of stuff in a `select` statement, including building new objects from the objects you have:

```
List<ClassB> foo(List<ClassA> listA)
{
    return lisA.Select(row => new ClassB(row, "stuff").ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) to project elements of listA into ClassB intances:

```
listA.Select(a => new ClassB(a, "stuff")).ToList()
```